# how to select which vector values sum up to a constant

Tags: c++, vector, sum

I've made a vector, but I don't know how to select variable to sum up to a certain sum.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int en;
    int boy;
    while((std::cout << "EN giriniz: ") && (std::cin >> en))
    {
        numbers.push_back(en); //numbers will resize itself automatically
        while((std::cout << "BOY giriniz: ") && (std::cin >> boy))
        {
            numbers.push_back(boy); //numbers will resize itself automatically
            break;
        }
    }
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = numbers.begin(); i != numbers.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    //...
}
```

Comment: thats an algorithm question not a c++ question. You should work it out with paper and pencil first -> Given a list of numbers how do you find a set that adds up to a given value. If you expect there to be a vector.FindValuesThatMakeSum(42) - there isnt

Comment: Do you want an efficient algorithm, or a simple one?

Comment: well its like this , there is a constant number of 600 , and there are many entries , i have to find the best entries that sums up to 600 , it means most efficient ones , so there is minimal left of 600.

Comment: i really appreciate it guys , I'm working on the algorithm for 2 days and I'm nowhere

Comment: @hesamrastad I seriously doubt that you were working on it for 2 days. Anyone could solve such an exercise if they sat at it for 2 days straight. Here's an algorithm for solving the problem: 1) Make the test case smaller 2) figure out the most efficient algorithm 3) increase test case 4) inspect if your algorithm still works 5) If not: improve it, so it works 6) Are you at original problem? If not, move to step 3. Done.

Comment: did you work it out with pen and paper first? this has nothing to do with code

Comment: you misunderstand @Beta question. He wants to know if you want a solution that finds the answer very fast but is hard to follow the code. Or if you want a one that is simple to code and understand but will be slower. Both solutions will give the correct answer

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius , thank you for rubbing my face in it , I've tries adding max and min of given numbers till they reach 600 , didn't work , I've tried dividing entries in 2 groups , zilch , nothing , I've tried to simple it down by writing 1-9 for entries and max limit of 20 , max+min+max+min... =<20 worked but in 600 it gets out of hand, anyway i need your help guys , thank you so much

Comment: @pm100 fast one would be the best option , considering number of entries , appreciate it

Comment: @hesamrastad 1) "Doesn't work" is such a vague problem statement, that it is useless. 2) Did you try to solve such a problem on paper, how did it go? If you can't solve it on paper, how do you expect to write code, that does it?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm asking you guys for help ..

Comment: @hesamrastad I just finished my answer describing both the brute force solution and the dynamic programming solution with code.

Comment: @hesamrastad I understood that, once I read your question. You didn't answer my questions, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This is one of my older answers. I wasn't as good back then, and now I know there is a much simpler, faster, and less memory-consuming solution to this problem. If we compute the DP bottom-up in a table that only stores the closest possible sum, we can reconstruct one of the subsets of numbers later using the table values we computed.

This is called a [binary knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem). In your case, an object's weight is its value (the number).

If you want a fast solution that runs in O(NW) where N is the number of numbers and W is the target value (can do 10,000 number problems in a fraction of a second), use dynamic programming as in the Wikipedia link. Some other algorithms are also described there.

For a brute force solution that runs in O(N2^N), basically, try all possible combinations of numbers to pick and remember the best one. You can do this with [recursion](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) (scroll down to recursivity), or bit operations where you have an integer and each bit of it represents whether to include a number in the set or not, and you simply increment it.

If you have trouble implementing it, here's my code for the fast dynamic programming algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int N, W; //N = number of numbers, W = target sum
vector<int> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

pair<int, multiset<int>> calc(int i, int j) //returns closest sum and best subset of the first i numbers for the target value j
{
    static map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, multiset<int>>> dp; //stores results to avoid repeated calculations
    pair<int, int> p(i, j); //pair for convenience
    if(i == 0) //base case
    {
        return make_pair(0, multiset<int>(
        {}));
    }
    auto findResult = dp.find(p);
    if(findResult != dp.end()) //check if already calculated
    {
        return findResult->second;
    }
    auto temp1 = calc(i - 1, j); //compute result if not using number
    if(numbers[i - 1] > j) //if current number is too big
    {
        return temp1;
    }
    auto temp2 = calc(i - 1, j - numbers[i - 1]); //compute result if using number
    temp2.first += numbers[i - 1];
    temp2.second.insert(numbers[i - 1]);
    pair<int, multiset<int>> result;
    if(temp1.first != temp2.first) //compare results and choose best
    {
        result = temp1.first > temp2.first ? temp1 : temp2;
    }
    else
    {
        result = temp1.second.size() < temp2.second.size() ? temp1 : temp2;
    }
    dp.insert(make_pair(p, result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter target sum: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    pair<int, multiset<int>> result = calc(N, W); //calculate
    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << result.first << ", obtained using the set of numbers {";
    if(result.second.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << *result.second.begin();
        for(auto i = ++result.second.begin(); i != result.second.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << ", " << *i;
        }
    }
    cout << "}.\n";
}
```

And here is the simple brute force with bit operations (note that this solution can only compute the solution with less than 32 items due to the 32-bit integer used to store the state. Any more takes an extremely long time to run anyways):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int N, W; //N = number of numbers, W = target sum
vector<int> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter target sum: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    int bestSum = -1, bestSolution; //stores current best solution
    for(unsigned int current = 0; current < (1 << N); current++) //current represents current set
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //compute sum
        {
            if(current & (1 << i))
            {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
        }
        if(sum <= W && sum > bestSum) //update best
        {
            bestSum = sum;
            bestSolution = current;
        }
    }
    multiset<int> result; //make result set for output
    int resultSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(bestSolution & (1 << i))
        {
            result.insert(numbers[i]);
            resultSum += numbers[i];
        }
    }
    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << resultSum << ", obtained using the set of numbers {";
    if(result.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << *result.begin();
        for(auto i = ++result.begin(); i != result.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << ", " << *i;
        }
    }
    cout << "}.\n";
}
```

A solution that outputs all sets of numbers with sum equal to the greatest possible sum not greater than the target value and containing the least possible number of numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int N, W; //N = number of numbers, W = target sum
vector<int> numbers; //stores the set of numbers

pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> calc(int i, int j) //returns closest sum and best subset of the first i numbers for the target value j
{
    static map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, set<multiset<int>>>> dp; //stores results to avoid repeated calculations
    pair<int, int> p(i, j); //pair for convenience
    if(i == 0) //base case
    {
        set<multiset<int>> temp;
        temp.emplace();
        return make_pair(0, temp);
    }
    auto findResult = dp.find(p);
    if(findResult != dp.end()) //check if already calculated
    {
        return findResult->second;
    }
    auto temp1 = calc(i - 1, j); //compute result if not using number
    if(numbers[i - 1] > j) //if current number is too big
    {
        return temp1;
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> temp2 = calc(i - 1, j - numbers[i - 1]), newtemp2; //compute result if using number
    newtemp2.first = temp2.first + numbers[i - 1];
    for(const auto k : temp2.second)
    {
        multiset<int> temp = k;
        temp.insert(numbers[i - 1]);
        newtemp2.second.insert(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> *result;
    if(temp1.first != newtemp2.first) //compare results and choose best
    {
        result = temp1.first > newtemp2.first ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else if(temp1.second.begin()->size() != newtemp2.second.begin()->size())
    {
        result =
                temp1.second.begin()->size() < newtemp2.second.begin()->size() ? &temp1 : &newtemp2;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.second.insert(newtemp2.second.begin(), newtemp2.second.end());
        result = &temp1;
    }
    dp.insert(make_pair(p, *result));
    return *result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of numbers: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter target sum: ";
    cin >> W;
    numbers.reserve(N); //avoid extra reallocations
    cout << "Enter the numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) //input loop
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    pair<int, set<multiset<int>>> result = calc(N, W); //calculate
    //output below
    cout << "The best possible sum is " << result.first << ", which can be obtained using a set of "
            << result.second.begin()->size() << " numbers " << result.second.size()
            << " different ways:\n";
    for(const auto &i : result.second)
    {
        cout << '{';
        if(i.size() > 0)
        {
            cout << *i.begin();
            for(auto j = ++i.begin(); j != i.end(); ++j)
            {
                cout << ", " << *j;
            }
        }
        cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for our code , really appreciate it

Comment: @hesamrastad If this solved your problem please click accept on my answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: and i have a question , your code is perfect but only shows 1 line of answer , i need to show all the answers. like this : 
{a, b, c, d}
{e, f, g, h}
...
thank you so much

Comment: I thought you only wanted the best possible set (sum closest to the target value). What do you mean by all answers? There should be an accept button somewhere in my answer. I don't know exactly where because I never asked a question that got answered, but it should be something like a check mark or "accept".

Comment: @hesamrastad To accept an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/9254539

Comment: this program should work till all the entries are sorted and shown in the result , for example, now it shows just 1 sets of entries for best possible sum , but other entries are now shown, we have to get all the best sums of all the entries .
i really appreciate it if you could help me with this.
in the men time I'm learning about accepting and answer .
waiting for your reply , really appreciate it .

Comment: and there shouldn't be any repetitions 
thank you so much

Comment: Hmm... ok. I'll work on it. It's a good opportunity to practice some coding.

Comment: this question was a mess , so i asked an other one , I'm mainly waiting for your answer because as it seems you are the one who is going to solve it .

Comment: @hesamrastad Done! See the edited answer. This might not be the best code but it works fine.

Comment: can you post it to my second question so ? i have already accepted your answer for this question , and your rock man

Comment: it works fine but show all the answers not the best ones ,how could we only just show the best ones ?

Comment: and there is repetition in the answer, waiting for your kind reply

Comment: It should only show the sets that sum to the target value, or the greatest possible value if the target can not be achieved. If you only want one of them, see the other answer. Do you want it to only print the sets with the least number of numbers in them?

Comment: If there is some repetition I really can't do anything about it since it has to do with how the standard library containers are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to do

```
n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5
```

until you win or are > target number

Then do

```
n0 + n2 + n3 + ....
```

No luck

```
n0 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6...
```

When you exhaust the list restart with

```
n1 + n2 + n3
```

then

```
 n1 + n3 + n4
```

etc.

This is the 'simple' aka 'brute force' approach. Others will have many many suggested tricks for going faster

Comment: thank you but is it going to find the most efficient numbers ?

Comment: so target = 600